# position:fixed – OK in IE7 and IE9+ but not in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to get `position:fixed` working in **IE8** for my sticky-on-scroll navigation.

The script, etc. is sticks the div `#sticky` to the top whenever then user scrolls past it, and vice versa

http://jsfiddle.net/bDGGC/

It works great in IE7 and >IE9 — and quirks/compatability mode in IE8 — but I can't seem to get it working in standards mode in IE8 (it "doesn't stick").

I have tried adding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN”>
```

Does not help…

Anyone got a clue?

Comment: It's hard to figure from the code you provided. Seems like you are returning something which doesn't necessarily apply the CSS. Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @JeevanRose http://jsfiddle.net/bDGGC/ – thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing the doctype to <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: @JeevanJose I am afraid that does not ameliorate the situation

Comment: @Liam it sticks the div (#sticky) to the top whenever then user scrolls past it, and vice versa

Comment: This is actually working fine for me.

Comment: @salient this sounds like a common doctype problem. Try this: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`